# Mismo prefijo pero diferente middleware en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy creando un panel donde podrán entrar usuarios y profesores pero quiero que dependiendo del rol te cargue una vista u otra pero manteniendo la misma ruta, el problema viene con que al entrar a dicha ruta se va directamente al último grupo.

```php
//CLIENT
Route::group(['middleware' => 'user', 'prefix' => 'dashboard', 'namespace' => 'user'], function () {
    Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\User\HomeController::class, 'home'])->name('user.inicio');
});

//TEACHER
Route::group(['middleware' => 'teacher', 'prefix' => 'dashboard', 'namespace' => 'teacher'], function () {
    Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\Teacher\HomeController::class, 'home'])->name('teacher.inicio');
});
```

Comment: creo que te falta un simple if.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No soy un Experto en laravel pero creo que con un `if` lo resuelves ( o operador ternario).

la idea seria separar la carga de la vista analizando el usuario Loggeado:

```
return namespace=='user' ? $this->user():$this->teacher();
```

Luego:

```
//User
public function User(){
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'user', 'prefix' => 'dashboard', 'namespace' => 'user'], function () {
        Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\User\HomeController::class, 'home'])->name('user.inicio');
    });
}


//TEACHER
public function Teacher(){
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'teacher', 'prefix' => 'dashboard', 'namespace' => 'teacher'], function () {
        Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\Teacher\HomeController::class, 'home'])->name('teacher.inicio');
    });
}
```

incluso si lo que deseas es hacerlo dinámico para tipos de usuarios a la N:

```
    $userType = session['userType']; //teache or user or lo que sea
    Route::group(['middleware' => $userType, 'prefix' => 'dashboard', 'namespace' => $userType], function () {
        Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\.$userType.\HomeController::class, 'home'])->name($userType.'.inicio');
    });
```

Comment: No es exactamente lo que tenia pensado para la solución pero es un buen apaño.

Comment: en teoría cuando necesitas acceso dinámicos debes pensar que son objetos mutables y tienes que agregarle soporte a ese entorno dinámico ... se ve mas cuando programas arquitecturas SPA.